# How do I fix 'ValueError: callback must be a callable, got 18:19:46'

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, mobile-application, kivymd

So I'm trying to get a good grasp on kivy and I want to create a basic clock app and I keep running into a problem when I go to update the clock label. I've looked at other threads on here and still cant find the right solution. I believe I am doing something wrong at Clock.schedule_interval but again, I'm trying to get a grasp on kivy and I'm not sure. Any help would be greatly appriciated

Python code

````
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
import time

Builder.load_file('myApp.kv')

class ClockScreen(Widget):
    def updateClock(self):
        hour = time.strftime("%H")
        minute = time.strftime("%M")
        second = time.strftime("%S")
        Clocktime = self.root.ids.clock.text
        print(Clocktime)
        newTime = self.root.ids.clock.text = f'{hour}:{minute}:{second}'
        return newTime


class FirstApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return ClockScreen()

    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(ClockScreen.updateClock(self), 1)



FirstApp().run()
```
````

KV File

:

```
FloatLayout:
    size: root.width, root.height

    Label:
        id: clock
        text: "12:00"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
def on_start(self):
    Clock.schedule_interval(ClockScreen.updateClock, 1)
```

Reason:

`ClockScreen.updateClock` is a callable (a function handle). [This is also explained in the docs](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html).

`ClockScreen.updateClock(self)` is actually calling the function that returns the time, and you cannot schedule a string (`18:19:46`, as per your error).

---

However, this doesn't say which *instance* of the ClockScreen gets updated (you are referencing the function via a class rather than a specific instance), so this may be more accurate for what you want

```
class FirstApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return ClockScreen()

    def on_start(self):
        cs = self.build()
        Clock.schedule_interval(cs.updateClock, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, it got me a little closer. Its saying callback must be a callable, got none but at least its not the error I got before

Comment: That's literally the same error, just a different return type

Comment: I don't know Kivy all too well, but I think you're going to need a partial function (refer linked docs) that can pass in the clock that you want to update

Comment: I fixed it this first try this morning, guess I just needed to get some sleep and stop looking at one thing haha. Thanks for the help I appriciate it. I was missing the *args in my update clock method which I ended up moving to the the FirstApp class.